# In ubuntu14.04LTS microphone not working

Tags: 14.04, microphone

I have installed skype on Dell 3420 Ubuntu 14.04LTS but I am not able to hear the voice.
Microphone is not working I think. I am new to Ubuntu so can anyone help.

Comment: Very difficult to provide an answer based on no information. Perhaps you'll want to check in Sound Settings to see if you've chosen the correct input?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html

*The command above replaces "skype" from the Skype desktop file with "env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype", this being a work-around for getting Skype to work with PulseAudio 4.0. 
If you want to launch Skype from a script or add it to Startup Applications, use the following command: "env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype" instead of "skype".*